# invalid breakpoint with xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a breakpoint falsely getting hit.  I have cleaned and rebuilt, deleted my project from the simulator and even tried rebooting but the problem persists.  I have a breakpoint that stops ever time at the line "hasEstimateNumberChanged = YES;".  However when I view the logs it does not print "inside hasEstimateNumberChanged test" to the console.  And the log also displays "hasEstimateNumberChanged = 0".  I'm at a loss at why it's hitting this.

```
        BOOL hasEstimateNumberChanged = NO;
        if (![survey.Code_Sub_Cmpy_Est isEqualToString:[estimateField1.text uppercaseString]] 
                || [survey.Nbr_Agt_Est compare:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:estimateField2.text]] != NSOrderedSame 
                || ![survey.Nbr_Est isEqualToString:[estimateField3.text uppercaseString]]) {

            NSLog(@"inside hasEstimateNumberChanged test");
            hasEstimateNumberChanged = YES;
        }  
        NSLog(@"hasEstimateNumberChanged = %d", hasEstimateNumberChanged);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with no optimizations (`None [-O0]`)? That setting is normally associated with a debug scheme build configuration. Compiler optimizations can really confuse the debugger.

Comment: That was it.  I had created another Scheme and missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. I'll upgrade that to an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're compiling with no optimizations (`None [-O0]`)? That setting is normally associated with a debug scheme build configuration. Compiler optimizations can really confuse the debugger.