# Xcode Breakpoint is off

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am incorporating some C code in my objective-C project. My break point is off in that C part of the code.  I noticed on [invalid breakpoint with xcode 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845387/invalid-breakpoint-with-xcode-4-3) that some optimization can mess with it. But I'm not sure where the optimization option is on Xcode 4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you just want to change the build settings for optimization in Xcode?

If thats what you mean then you can click on your project to bring up the build info. Select your target on the right of the build info screen, then type optimization into the search bar on the upper right corner of the window.  It should show you right where to change it.

Cheers

Comment: yeah, it was a simple question and I just had no idea where it was at. Thanks. :)